# Get errorlevel after cancel the installation

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

Am running one batch file which will start one third party .exe file , for example

**start /wait /d MSVC++_2005.exe**

Here based on errorlevel I want to do some cleanup activities.Now the question is all the time mean to say **even on success and on failure am getting the same errorlevel as "0"**.

Need some clarification on errorlevel, when will get the non-zero for error level based on this issue.

Can anyone please help me to get the errorlevel based on result.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: The thirdparty program should say in its documentation what errorlevel value it returns in what case. But many (badly written) DOS or Windows program allways return 0. Test your logic with a program you are confident in.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
start "" /wait /b MSVC++_2005.exe
if errorlevel 1 echo error & pause
```